# Get the list of STRIPE customer Payments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I've a list of customers on Stripe Account. Now the customers have done the monthly payments also, I want the list of the payments of particular customer.

I've used this :

```
StripeCustomerService stripeCustomerInfo = new StripeCustomerService();
var customerInfo = stripeCustomerInfo.Get("customerId");
```

But `customerInfo` doesn't displays the list of his payments that he has done so far.

Comment: you probably need to use StripeChargeService class

Comment: StripeInvoiceService worked for me. But will try your idea also. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @HemantBhagat Post your own answer as Answer if you have resolved it. That might help others in need.

Comment: @Rohit Arora please check. I've answered the question now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the payments are made & invoices are generated. So i simply get the info using Invoice Service of Stripe like mentioned below :

```
StripeInvoiceService invoiceService = new StripeInvoiceService();
var invoicesOfCustomer = invoiceService.List(10, 0, "CustomerId");
```

now `invoicesOfCustomer` will have a list of all the payments that he has done.

If you have `invoiceId` then you can use this for single invoice info.

```
var invoiceInfo = invoiceService.Get("invoiceId");
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Invoices are not generated automatically while charging. How are you getting payment info with the invoice?

Comment: I'm just getting the list of invoices already generated. He just asked to get the list of invoices that are generated.